# "Wild Symbol" for Slots Program?

Tags: python

Be gentle, I'm brand new to programming! For my first project, I'm working on a 3 reel slot machine program. Just got to the point of making a "Wild Symbol" out of the integer 1. Is there a simpler way to code it because it feels inelegant? Thank you!

```
#3 wheel slot machine code
ri1 = random.randint(1, 20)
ri2 = random.randint(1, 20)
ri3 = random.randint(1, 20)
print(ri1, ri2, ri3)

if ri1 == ri2 == ri3:
    print("Win")
elif ri1 == 1 and ri2 == ri3:
    print("Win")
elif ri2 == 1 and ri1 == ri3:
    print("Win")
elif ri1 == ri2 and ri3 == 1:
    print("Win")
elif ri1 == 1 and ri2 == 1:
    print("Win")
elif ri1 == 1 and ri3 == 1:
    print("Win")
elif ri2 == 1 and ri3 == 1:
    print("Win")
elif ri1 == 20 and ri2 == 20 and ri3 == 20:
    print("Jackpot")
else:
    print("Play Again")
```

Comment: As a side note, `elif ri1 == 20 and ri2 == 20 and ri3 == 20:` can't happen, because `if ri1 == ri2 == ri3:` would pick it up instead.

Comment: If this is working, but you want tips on improving it, you may want codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I didn't even realize that existed!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to check for duplicates is to build a `set` of the values. For this specific case, we can build the `set`, remove `1` if it appears, and *then* see if there's at most one unique value. (If there are *no* remaining values, then all of the inputs were `1`, which is also a win.)

```
results = {ri1, ri2, ri3}
results.discard(1)
if results == {20}:
    print("Jackpot")
elif len(x) <= 1:
    print("Win")
else:
    print("Play again")
```